# AngularJS - Execution of code after "ng-bind-html" completes

Tags: angularjs

My current problem is getting a specific set of code to run after Angular is finished binding a string of HTML with ng-bind-html. My reasons for doing this are a lot more complicated than the JSFiddle provided below (it involves calculations of SVGs) but the base principle and example of the issue can be seen there.

Does anyone know if there's another angular function I can insert code into that is guaranteed to run once ng-bind-html is finished doing what it needs to do?

I'm completely new to AngularJS so apologies if ng-bind-html is the wrong way to go about doing this when attempting to execute code once its finished. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="lot" ng-bind-html="renderHtml('<span>hello</span>')">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wnn7uv3e/2/

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is but if the result is DOM manipulation then you need to do that in a directive and NOT in a controller. With a directive you could simply wrap the HTML you wish to manipulate and have the directive modify it as needed in either the link or compile phases.

Comment: Yeah, the Fiddle doesn't provide everything I was dealing with but I ended up making a custom directive to have more control of when the HTML gets rendered. The drawback to ng-bind-html seems to be that there is no way of telling when the HTML is finished parsing into the document thus forcing the use of a timeout if you want to manipulate that parsed HTML. 

Anyway, a custom directive gave me what I needed. Thanks for the idea, @mccainz.

Comment: What did you do in the directive?